# 404 Error when running Flask app on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, flask

I'm attempting to build a very simple Flask application using just Flask and Python. No databases or other plugins. The application runs perfectly fine on my local machine and I can navigate without errors, but when I deploy to Heroku, I receive a 404 Not Found error for any page that I try to visit, including the index.

Here's my site's layout: 
[Site Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0vhy.png)

mbtaCrTracker.py is the root of my app. Here's what it currently looks like:

```
from mbtaCrTracker import app
from mbtaCrTracker import views
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Here's my _ init _.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Here's my views.py:

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect
from mbtaCrTracker import app
from getTrainInfo import getTrainInfo

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/map', methods=['GET'])
def findTrain():
    line = request.args.get('line')
    direction = request.args.get('direction')
    coords = getTrainInfo(line, direction)
    return render_template('map.html', coords=coords)
```

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn mbtaCrTracker:app --log-file=-
```

I think everything is set up properly because I'm able to run the app locally without any issues. When I deploy to Heroku, I can see that the site is Up, not Crashed, and I'm not receiving any server errors, just Not Found errors. It's almost as if my routes aren't working or something like that.

Here's what I see in my Heroku logs when I try to access my site's homepage:

```
2017-11-06T12:23:17.717474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn mbtaCrTracker:app --log-file=-`
2017-11-06T12:23:19.795333+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-11-06 12:23:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-11-06T12:23:19.796263+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-11-06 12:23:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:43494 (4)
2017-11-06T12:23:19.796405+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-11-06 12:23:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-11-06T12:23:19.800312+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-11-06 12:23:19 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2017-11-06T12:23:19.810431+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-11-06 12:23:19 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2017-11-06T12:23:21.351354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-11-06T12:23:29.564508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mbtacrtracker.herokuapp.com request_id=cdae33d9-9f9d-4568-b619-b6c10bb34e9b fwd="172.58.216.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=404 bytes=386 protocol=https
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like the app is listening at port 43494. Is this the port you are trying to access? Do you have any routing specified? Any ports need to be opened?

Comment: It seems like Heroku picks a random port every time the app stops and restarts. For example, I just started it again, and it's now using port 16469. If I try accessing the app at that port, I get "This site can't be reached." I haven't required any specific port in my app. Should I?

I do have some routes which I've included in my original post.

Comment: I think that is the gunicorn picking the port, but I'm not entirely sure. What happens if you specify port where you also specify host? `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=1337)`

Comment: I have tried specifying a port, but it didn't seem to make any different. I still received a 404 when accessing the app, and if I try accessing the app:port, I get "This site can't be reached". :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some steps you may follow to successfully deploy on Heroku:

Rename `mbtaCrTracker.py` to `app.py`

Cut the contents of `mbtaCrTracker` to root directory. Delete the `mbtaCrTracker` directory.

`app.py` should contain:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from getTrainInfo import getTrainInfo

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/map', methods=['GET'])
def findTrain():
    line = request.args.get('line')
    direction = request.args.get('direction')
    coords = getTrainInfo(line, direction)
    return render_template('map.html', coords=coords)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`Procfile` contains:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

And one simple way to deploy this is to push this in `github` and then link the `github` repository with the app in `heroku`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! 

When I was first following the setup tutorial, I had named my app "app", but shortly after, I changed app to mbtaCrTracker because it felt confusing to type "from app import app" and I wanted to add some clarity.  

Is there a way to get this working on Heroku without combing my routes/views with everything else? I prefer to keep it all separate for a cleaner design, but if that's not possible then I suppose I could combine them and rename.

Comment: At first try this and ensure everything is running smoothly in heroku. Obviously we can separate views from models. Check [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/)

Comment: Okay, so I went ahead and changed my project structure following your recommendations. I'm able to start the app, but when I try to access it, I get a 404 Not Found, just like I do on Heroku. I can now exactly reproduce the error locally.  

Now I just need to figure out why... I have routes, but it's almost as if they aren't working.

Comment: Have you run any Flask app in localhost? If the answer is yes, paste the error trace here.

Comment: So after changing to your folder structure, I forgot to move 
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
to the bottom. I had accidentally pasted it at the top with 
    app = Flask(__name__)
so it wasn't working.

After moving this to the bottom and restarting the app, it's working great! Thank you so much for your help!